# How to enable the React Semantic UI Modal to stretch across the full screen?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

This is my first time trying to use Meteor with ReactJs and React Semantic UI, and having issues on rendering the Semantic UI modal. What I am trying to achieve is to click on the button and open up the modal overlaying on the whole browser, in reference to the [React Semantic Modal Manual](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal#modal-example-basic)  But what I have right now is that the modal is rendered partially on the screen, as seen from the attached screenshots. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Main.js

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {routes} from "../imports/routes/routes";

Meteor.startup(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Site.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Header, Button, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import PrivateHeader from './PrivateHeader';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import ModalExample from './Modal';

export class Site extends React.Component {
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PrivateHeader/>
                <Sidebar/>
                <div className="page">
                    <div className="ui padded one column grid">
                        <div className="column">
                            <ModalExample/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Site;
```

ModalExample.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Header, Icon, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const ModalBasicExample = () => (
    <Modal trigger={<Button>Basic Modal</Button>} basic size='fullscreen'>
        <Header icon='archive' content='Archive Old Messages' />
        <Modal.Content>
            <p>Your inbox is getting full, would you like us to enable automatic archiving of old messages?</p>
        </Modal.Content>
        <Modal.Actions>
            <Button basic color='red' inverted>
                <Icon name='remove' /> No
            </Button>
            <Button color='green' inverted>
                <Icon name='checkmark' /> Yes
            </Button>
        </Modal.Actions>
    </Modal>
)

export default ModalBasicExample
```

Sidebar.js

```
export const Sidebar = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="ui inverted vertical left fixed menu" >
            <a className="item" href="/">
                <img src='/images/logo.png' className="ui mini right spaced image"/>
                Semantics UI Test
            </a>

            <div className="item">
                <div className="header">Hosting</div>
                <div className="menu">
                    <a className="item">Shared</a>
                    <a className="item">Dedicated</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="item">
                <div className="header">Support</div>
                <div className="menu">
                    <a className="item">E-mail Support</a>
                    <a className="item">FAQs</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
export default Sidebar;
```

[image: Basic Modal Button]
[image: Rendered Modal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Saad's comment mentioning the className that I found out that it was due to Semantic UI will add a `ui page modals dimmer transition visible active` className when the modal is opened. This causes a conflict to my existing `page` className which is used in other pages, but because of Meteor and React, the various scss are compressed together.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to run `this.show('fullscreen')` with an `onClick` event on  trigger button like the following :

```
<Button onClick={this.show('fullscreen')}>Show Modal</Button>
```

**ModalExample.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class ModalExample extends Component {
  state = { open: false }

  show = size => () => this.setState({ size, open: true })
  close = () => this.setState({ open: false })

  render() {
    const { open, size } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.show('fullscreen')}>Show Modal</Button> // Triggering button

        <Modal size={size} open={open} onClose={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header>
            Delete Your Account
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Content>
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete your account</p>
          </Modal.Content>
          <Modal.Actions>
            <Button negative>
              No
            </Button>
            <Button positive icon='checkmark' labelPosition='right' content='Yes' />
          </Modal.Actions>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ModalExample
```

[Source](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal#modal-example-size)

Comment: Tried, but that didn't work for my case. It just changed the modal presentation but the modal is still displayed like the attached screen above. The overlay modal still does not cover the whole screen.

Comment: Try just adding `className="fullscreen modal"` to your modal.

Comment: thanks for your response and help. I finally found out it was due to a conflict of className when the modal is rendered.